# Keeping checkboxes aligned using the Exam class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol, exam, forms

I'm using the exam class in a multicols environment to create a series of worksheets. Many questions are yes/no. If the question is too long, it wraps to the next line and moves the answers. Is there a way to "anchor" the answer yes/no checkboxes to always appear right aligned on the first line and wrap the text of the question appropriately?

Below is the way I can currently formatting yes/no questions. A solution would not hopefully not require the way questions are currently written to be changed since there are quite a few legacy documents. Also, a solution can't modify *every* question, because not every question is yes/no.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand\YesNo{%
\hfill\mbox{\begin{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice Yes
    \choice No
\end{oneparcheckboxes}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{questions}
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line\YesNo

... % lots of questions go here

\end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Currently looks like...
[image]

Should look like...
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would using `t`op-aligned `\parbox`es work?

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\newcommand\YesNo{%
\hfill\mbox{\begin{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice Yes
    \choice No
\end{oneparcheckboxes}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{questions}
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line}\YesNo
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line}\YesNo
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line}\YesNo
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line}\YesNo
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line}\YesNo
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line}\YesNo
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line}\YesNo
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line}\YesNo
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line}\YesNo
\question This question is short\YesNo
\question \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{This question is longer, and will probably wrap to the next line}\YesNo
\end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The choice of `\parbox` width (`0.5\linewidth`) may be varied depending on the multiple choice style.

Comment: This does work, but can be a little tedious. This might be wishful thinking, but is there any way to bind this behavior to the \yesno macro so that existing documents would not need to be modified?